# What is the efficient way to make a static local object thread safe in a static function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, static, thread-safety, msvc12

I am analyzing a crash dump and found that I have a race condition in the local static object initialization. I am using MSVC++12.0 which doesn't have a thread safe static initialization.

Here is the minimal version of the program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <Windows.h>

class internalClass
{
public:
    internalClass(int parm) : value(parm) {}
    int value;
};

class externalClass
{
public:
    externalClass(int parm)
    {
        Sleep(1000*10);
        dp = new internalClass(parm);

    }
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << dp->value << "\n";
    }
    ~externalClass()
    {
        delete dp;
    }
    internalClass *dp;
};

static void foo()
{
    static externalClass obj(50);
    obj.print();
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(foo);
    Sleep(1000);
    std::thread t2(foo);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

In the main program, externalClass is actually used for resource synchronization.

Comment: You can avoid the thread safety issue by ensuring that the first call to `foo` is before you start threads.  Call `foo` from `main` before you create the first thread.  In this case you'd probably want to add something to not call `obj.print()` when you do that.

Comment: Is static member variable thread safe? So that I  can put  static variable as part of a class

Comment: If I put externalClass as static object in a class, then it will be initialized before the threads starts. Does this approach have any issue ?

Comment: @nonock can you share some examples for object construction using atomic. All I seeing is using atomic on integral types

Comment: A static member variable (or global variable) will be initialized before `main` starts execution.  Threading is usually not a concern at this point unless some initializer creates them.  There can be issues with order of initialization for variables declared in different translation units.

Comment: just googled: https://www.drdobbs.com/testing/debugging-multithreaded-applications-in/240158201     
As part of the debugger, Visual Studio provides a "Threads" window that lists all of the current threads in the system. From this window, you can:   
Freeze (suspend) or thaw (resume) a thread. This is useful when you want to observe the behavior of your application without a certain thread running.
Switch the current active thread...